# Appending the same list to another one

Tags: python

I have to append the same list to another one more than one time, and then modify only one of them.
I tried

```
list_a = []
list_b = [0,0,0]
for x in range(3):
    list_a.append(list_b)
```

but the problem is that if I try

```
list_a[0][0] = 1
```

it modifies `list_a[1][0]` and `list_a[2][0]` also.
How can I avoid that?

Comment: `list_a.append(list_b[:])` -- append copies of `list_b` instead of the original

Comment: Really thank you! @khelwood

Comment: "I have to append the same list to another one more than one time" - and now you have the *same list* appended to the other one several times, which is the problem. You need to make multiple lists instead of reusing the same one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
list_a = []
list_b = [0,0,0]
for x in range(3):
    list_a.append(list_b[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to create a list like this if all you want is to create empty list with all `0`s is:

```
my_list = [[0]*3 for _ in range(3)]
```

Let's verify the result whether it has the same issue or not:

```
>>> my_list
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> my_list[0][0] = 1
>>> my_list
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
# ^          ^          ^
# Yipee! value changed only once
```

For knowing the reason why your code is not working, check: [*Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 0):

You are appending list_b three times, so what you are modifying is the actual list_b object. What you want to do is to make a shallow copy, this be done like this

```
list_a.append(list(list_b))
```

or like this

```
list_a.append(list_b[:])
```